# Cannot retrieve the "Received Date" from an Outlook Meeting by using Powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook

I have been trying (unsuccesfully) to obtain the "Received Date" for the meetings in my Calendar by using [this script](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-export-outlook-calendar-information/).

At first, I thought I could use the CreationTime property from IPM.Appointment object. Unfortunately, it seems that the property "CreationTime" gets updated when the meeting is modified (e.g. when the meeting is accepted), which makes me think that it's not the right property to use.

Is there any way to retrieve the actual date when the meeting was sent (or received)?

--------- EDIT (Code as this moment, removing comments) ---------

```
Function Get-OutlookCalendar {
 Add-type -assembly “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook” | out-null
 $olFolders = “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders” -as [type]
 $outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application
 $namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace(“MAPI”)
 $folder = $namespace.getDefaultFolder($olFolders::olFolderCalendar)
 $folder.items |
 Select-Object -Property Subject, Start, Duration, Location, CreationTime
}
```

Comment: Can you also add script as inline?

Comment: Done. I have removed comments and unnecessary spaces, but it's essentially the same code referenced by the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author - click IMessage button) if any properties (such as `PR_MESSAGE_DELIVERY_TIME`) will have the original value, but I don't think you will find anything: Outlook recreates the appointment from the scratch when a meeting update is received; this is by design, only the global appointment id remains the same.